# HKBiologicalSexObject.biologicalSex returns HKBiologicalSex instead of .Male or .Female

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have already authorized HealthKit, and I am getting BiologicalSex from HealthKitStore like this:

```
let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
var biologicalSexObject: HKBiologicalSexObject?
var biologicalSex: HKBiologicalSex?

do {
    biologicalSexObject = try healthKitStore.biologicalSex()
    biologicalSex = biologicalSexObject!.biologicalSex
} catch _ as NSError {
    biologicalSex = nil
    print("error reading biological sex")
}
```

However, when I try to print `biologicalSex` it returns `HKBiologicalSex` instead of `.Male` or `.Female`.

I have seen more or less this exact code in several tutorials, so I'm wondering if there have been any syntax changes I should be aware of in Swift 2.  (The error handling has changed, so I'm curious if anything else of note has.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rawValue` of `biologicalSex = biologicalSexObject!.biologicalSex` is required to do this.  The enum for BiologicalSex looks like this:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   HKBiologicalSexNotSet = 0,
   HKBiologicalSexFemale,
   HKBiologicalSexMale,
   HKBiologicalSexOther,
} HKBiologicalSex;
```

Using this information it is easy to design a switch statement to cover all of the possible values:

```
switch biologicalSex.rawValue{
    case 0:
        biologicalSex = nil
    case 1:
        biologicalSex = "Female"
    case 2:
        biologicalSex = "Male"
    case 3:
        biologicalSex = "Other"
    default:
        biologicalSex = nil
}
```

Comment: @Allan: you introduced `displayString` in your edit. Was this intentional? BTW, there's a really common (and mostly pointless) grammar pedant distinction between sex and gender that I *suspect* you're not actually referencing with these edits (Apple apparently has its own, somewhat more practical distinction in HealthKit?) - might wanna make it clear in your edit comments that you're side-stepping a potential error in the use of the library rather than just being pedantic about English.

Comment: @shog9: Why do you think the distinction is pointless?  They refer to different things, despite the very common misconception that they are the same.  It's not just being pedantic - conflating the terms is very insensitive to many people.

Comment: @shog9: I should have also mentioned that I was fixing a bug when introducing 'displayString'.  You cannot assign a string to a variable that is already an enum value.

Comment: @Allan Fixing bugs in other people answers is not a good idea at all... If you think this answer is wrong, post your own answer. (and indeed, this answer has problems, so a correct one would be welcomed).

Comment: in iOS 15.6 I’m unable to get Gender.